# Why my svg code is not getting displayed?

Tags: html, svg, xhtml

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                       <defs>
                                          <path id="prefix__a" d="M8 0c.19 0 .381.076.571.152 1.296.762 2.096 2.705 2.096 4.038v.905c0 .553.447 1 1 1h2.428c1.067 0 1.905.838 1.905 1.943v.038l-.762 6.057c0 1.029-.876 1.867-1.905 1.867H8c-1.029 0-2.095-.267-3.01-.724l-1.18-.571v-4.63c0-1.537.539-3.027 1.523-4.208l.191-.24c.863-1.14 1.333-2.534 1.333-3.97v-.514C6.857.495 7.39 0 8 0zM2.667 6.857c.228 0 .38.153.38.381v8.381c0 .229-.152.381-.38.381H.38C.152 16 0 15.848 0 15.619v-8.38c0-.23.152-.382.381-.382z"></path>
                                       </defs>
                                       <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                          <use fill="#6C7D93" class="fill" xlink:href="#prefix__a"></use>
                                       </g>
                                    </svg>
```

I'm trying to get this exported svg work in my html page but it doesn't work. It works perfectly when opened standalone on chrome and also on my code editor. But when I added the code inside my html page, it doesn't show up. On inspecting with Chrome, I could see an invisible box. How can I fix this? However, all other svgs inserted inside the same page works perfectfly.

Comment: have any of the other SVGs you're embedding got an element with id='prefix__a' because id values must be unique.

Comment: yes I use this same svg more than one time on the same page! Even after changing the ids, it didn't work

Comment: While inspecting the <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                          <use fill="#6C7D93" class="fill" xlink:href="#prefix__a"></use>
                                       </g> part becomes 0x0 but it is 16x16 in the case of other icons

Comment: The problem should be with the id I guess. I changed all the ids and it seems to work. Is it possible to modify this svg without those ids? because for other icons there's no use of ids.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                   <defs>
                                      <path id="prefix__a" d="M8 0c.19 0 .381.076.571.152 1.296.762 2.096 2.705 2.096 4.038v.905c0 .553.447 1 1 1h2.428c1.067 0 1.905.838 1.905 1.943v.038l-.762 6.057c0 1.029-.876 1.867-1.905 1.867H8c-1.029 0-2.095-.267-3.01-.724l-1.18-.571v-4.63c0-1.537.539-3.027 1.523-4.208l.191-.24c.863-1.14 1.333-2.534 1.333-3.97v-.514C6.857.495 7.39 0 8 0zM2.667 6.857c.228 0 .38.153.38.381v8.381c0 .229-.152.381-.38.381H.38C.152 16 0 15.848 0 15.619v-8.38c0-.23.152-.382.381-.382z"></path>
                                   </defs>
                                   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                      <use fill="#6C7D93" class="fill" xlink:href="#prefix__a"></use>
                                   </g>
                                </svg>
```

**Check**

If any of your CSS code is overriding the above SVG elements

Comment: Nope, none of my css styles override the svg elements